# Find out more information about how a database became empty?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've got a database on a SQL Server 2005. Before the weekend, I could open this database in SQL Server Management Studio and see Database Diagrams, Tables, Views etc. However, now when I click on the '+' on the Node, it just disappears, showing the database is empty.

I have full control over the server. How can I find out what made this database lose all its tables/data? Cheers

Comment: Did you leave SSMS/Object Explorer open over the weekend, or are you working with a new instance that you opened today?

Comment: New instance, machine was shut down and locked away all weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMSS 2005 Hides DB objects that you don't have access to. Is it possible that your access could have been changed over the weekend (ie the tables etc are still there, you just can't see them).

If by "full control over the server" you mean that you are a member of Administrators Group in Windows, its possible that the BuiltIn\Administrators group has been removed from being a SQL administrator in the sql server security configuration (its often regarded as bad practice to have BuiltIn\Administrators with these rights to SQL anyway).

Comment: When i click on it I get "The database [DatabaseName] is not accessible". So I assume it could be a permission issue, but were a small team, and I don't think anyones changed it over the weekend. However, are there any log files I can view which would show me this information?

Comment: I'm not sure if this stuff is logged. Is this only affecting one DB on the server? Can you still access other databases? Are there any applications that use the problem DB (that don't log in through integrated security).

Comment: Think we've located the issue now. Was a problem with an automatic restore. Thanks for your help.